# Detect embedded videos in page

Tags: html, video, html-parsing

Given a URL is there any elegant way to find embedded videos in this page?

I was thinking about utilizing the video.google.com API for that but beside being deprecated I couldn't see how this can be done there.

Ideally I would like to extract the embedding code for any embedded video but if there is any solution that would extract embed codes only for popular services (youtube, vimeo, etc) that would also be great.

The server side technology I use is .Net but I am open for methods implemented in other technologies.

Answer (score 1):

For popular services it shouldn't be a problem to write a bunch of regular expressions and match the site against them. You can also write them for the popular embeded players (JW Player, Flowplayer etc.) and the HTML5 "video" tag.

Comment: I guess indeed that brute force HTML parsing would work (good idea though about JWplayer and flowplayer). I was hoping for some magical service a-la google-video that indexes videos and can be queried through some API.

Comment: @Variant have you found your answer? I'm having the same problem as yours. :(

Comment: No... Can't even remember what I needed that for... Sorry